# Excessive hard disk activity at midnight

Tags: disk, 21.10

On my Ubuntu 21.10 Ubuntu desktop, which is sometimes on at midnight (if I happen to be awake and using it), a nightly event takes place where there is a lot of disk activity -- the red light for the HDD is blinking repeatedly, even though I'm not doing anything.  I don't know what it is, but it does cause the system to slow down.

I know it isn't a user-level or a root-level cronjob.  I've checked that.  So, I guess it's something that has been turned on by default.  I suppose I also have a slight concern that it's something done by an outside party, but I guess that's unlikely since midnight every night is a bit too predictable.

I have set up a backup program, but that program doesn't run at midnight.  It's possible it's just rotating log files or something.  Whatever it is, I just want to know what it is (and maybe move it to another time).

Anyway, what can I do to figure out what's causing this?  I have looked at the output of `top`, but nothing looks out of place.  Besides the user and root's `crontab`, is there anything else I should check?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try running a resource monitor (like `htop`) during this time, and see which process consumes most CPU?

Comment: You're experiencing some "cron" jobs, or scheduled timer jobs that do some housekeeping. Check with `systemctl list-timers` (maybe also `crontab -l`) the list of timers. They will also show you when they start again

Comment: What do your logs for that time say?

Comment: @kanehekili Thank you!  I didn't know about `systemctl list-timers`.  (It wasn't anything I set in `crontab`, though.)  Combined with the answer below, I was able to find the culprit to be `mlocate`.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the logs:

```
# Use the power of the date command to produce journalctl-friendly date format
alias tsjou='date '\''+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'\'''
```

Examples:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ tsjou
22-03-06 14:02:25
walt@bat:~(0)$ tsjou --date="23:45 yesterday"
22-03-05 23:45:00
```

To see the system logs around midnight:

```
sudo journalctl --since="$(tsjou --date="23:45 yesterday")" \
                --until="$(tsjou --date="00:15")"
```

Read `man date journalctl`. I have more `journalctl` hints at https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator?tab=profile You'll have to click the "Read more" button - I'm verbose.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I know about `journalctl`, but not well enough to make it useful for me.  Combining your suggestion with `systemctl list-timers` in the comments above, I found out that rotating logs, man-db regeneration, and `mlocate` were running simultaneously.  The first two finish in 30 seconds.  `mlocate` runs for about 20 minutes but says it consumed 1 min of CPU time.  I guess it has a lot of disk I/O...I will have to do something about it.  I did find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268130/can-i-disable-updatedb-mlocate) just now.  Thank you for reply and the hints!